# Address Lookup from SQL table (ArcSDE)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gis, esri

I'm new to development and particularly C#. Been thrown in the deep end here but learning quickly :)

I am developing a simple Mapping Web App in VS2008. I have the map window up and running in my form thanks to a web control supplied by Esri.

I now need to provide an address search facility on the form whereby the user can enter postocde, road name etc into boxes and the map window then zooms to this desired location.

I know this can be achieved using Google Maps addressing etc but I need to use an Address table from our database (ArcSDE). My boss has suggested using SQLDataReader in .net to achieve this? Our address table includes columns for road name, postcode etc and a X and Y for each record (points).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the X Y for each record, you could just query the database for the supplied address (with SqlDataReader or any other kind of database access technology) and use that to zoom to the correct coordinates.  Also, what API are you using for your map.  I assume it's ESRI (i.e., Flex for ArcGIS).  I think you can actually include a control in ESRI's api that provides a geocoding service, which you could use to get the coordinates from you database as well.